# Unsupported column aliasing oracle

Tags: sql, database, oracle

I have problem, because I get error unsupported column aliasing and I dont't know where is the cause. Does anyone know the answer and can help? Thanks in advance :) Code:

```
with
ContractByRole (intermediary_nr, beneficiary_role, contract_nr) as (
  select intermediary_nr, beneficiary_role, max(contract_nr) contract_nr
  from boscs.atcs_commission_beneficiary
  where beneficiary_role in( 'LEAD', 'SUP_FOR_LEAD', 'COAGENT' )
      and intermediary_nr is not null
  group by intermediary_nr, beneficiary_role
)

AllRoles(contract_nr) as (
  select   contract_nr
  from     ContractByRole
  group by contract_nr
  having count(*) = 3
)

select  cbr.*
from    ContractByRole cbr
join    AllRoles       ar
    on  ar.contract_nr = cbr.contract_nr;
```

Error show in this place:

```
ContractByRole(intermediary_nr, beneficiary_role, contract_nr) as (
```

Comment: And exact the error message is?

Comment: ORA-32033:
unsupported column aliasing

Comment: You seem to be missing a `,` before `AllRoles(contract_nr) as `?

Comment: a = single. You are missing `,` is what it looks like to me.

Comment: And that is what is the issue, a `comma` to separate the two `subqueries`

Comment: I add "," in this place and I have the same error.

Comment: What happens if you change `ContractByRole (intermediary_nr, beneficiary_role, contract_nr) as (` to `ContractByRole as (` and `AllRoles(contract_nr) as (` to `AllRoles as (`? i.e. removing the column names in the definition. I would suggest deleting the line having `with` word and typing it. There could be extra characters which could be causing it. This could happen if you copied the sql from some web based source.

Comment: You can correct in code? because I don't know what do you mean

Comment: What Oracle version are you using? I don't know when column aliasing in WITH clauses was introduced, but your Oracle version might be too old to suppor it.

Comment: @DamianR: Look at Lalit's reply below, from which you can copy.

Comment: and if anyone knows how to convert it to normal without the clause with the query?

Comment: @DamianR, check the edit in the answer.

Comment: What do you mean with "*convert it to normal*"? Normal what?

Comment: no clause with, and with the queries

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have missed a comma to seperate the two subqueries in your WITH clause -

**Edit** Try this : (Not sure if you really need the recursive subquery)

```
WITH contractbyrole 
     AS 
     ( 
              SELECT   intermediary_nr, 
                       beneficiary_role, 
                       Max(contract_nr) contract_nr 
              FROM     boscs.atcs_commission_beneficiary 
              WHERE    beneficiary_role IN( 'LEAD', 
                                           'SUP_FOR_LEAD', 
                                           'COAGENT' ) 
              AND      intermediary_nr IS NOT NULL 
              GROUP BY intermediary_nr, 
                       beneficiary_role 
     ) 
    , --> here is the missing comma
     allroles 
     AS 
     ( 
              SELECT   contract_nr 
              FROM     contractbyrole 
              GROUP BY contract_nr 
              HAVING   count(*) = 3 
     ) 
SELECT cbr.* 
FROM   contractbyrole cbr 
JOIN   allroles ar 
ON     ar.contract_nr = cbr.contract_nr;
```

Comment: and if anyone knows how to convert it to normal without the clause with the query?